# React Laravel - File showing in state but not in controller

Tags: reactjs, laravel, redux, axios

My project has React as frontend and Laravel as backend.
I am trying to upload a file and the details of the file appear in state while uploading but not in the controller and hence not able to upload it in folder.

Component has

```
<div className="form-group col-sm-4">
   <div className="imgPreview">{$imagePreview}</div>
   <label>Profile Pic</label>
   <input className="form-control" type="file" name="profile_pic" onChange={(e)=>this._handleImageChange(e)}/>
</div>
```

further codes are:

```
_handleImageChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = e.target.files[0];    
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      this.setState({
        fileselected:           file,
        profile_pic:            file.name,
        imagePreviewUrl:        reader.result
      });
    }    
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
  }
```

Data gets uploaded though axios

```
 submitHandler = e =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.drprofilecreate(this.state)
}

export const drprofilecreate = (data) => dispatch =>{
console.log("Coming form profile create action ")
console.log(data)
return  axios.post('/api/v1/drProfileCreate', data)
.then( res =>res.data )
    .then(drprofile =>
        dispatch({
            type: DRPROFILECREATE,
            payload: drprofile,
        }),            
    )
}
```

When I view the data being uploaded, it shows the file with its details like name, size etc. But the same does not come in the controller. It shows a blank array.

```
 public function drProfileCreate(Request $request){
    $data = $request->all();
    $response = [
        'success'       =>true, 
        'datax'          =>'Dr Profile uploaded in Contorller. Check',
        'data'          => $data
    ];
    return response()->json($response, 201);
}
```

Hence Iam not able to upload the image. Help please. Appreciated
[image]

Comment: You have a duplicate key `data` in your response array in PHP

Comment: Well, I changed one of the keys and it still didn't work.... Will edit the question anyways. Thanks